# How to "use" a function type defined in an interface

Tags: typescript

Given an interface:

```
interface MyProps {
  onEvent: (name: string, data: any) => void;
}
```

How can I use that function type to prevent unused parameter errors when compiling?

```
eventHandler = (name: string, data: any) => {
  console.log(data);
}
```

Because currently I get a compilation error of unused parameter for the "name", but I cannot remove it because it would break the signature of the underlying type.

I was hoping to do something like this, although obviously this doesn't work!

```
eventHandler: MyProps.onEvent = (name, data) => {
  console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Are you using `noUnusedParameters` in the tsconfig? Other than that TypeScript does not care about it..

Comment: Cannot access `MyProps.onEvent` because `MyProps` is a type, but not a namespace. Did you mean to retrieve the type of the property `onEvent` in `MyProps` with `MyProps["onEvent"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have the syntax a bit wrong you need to use `['name']`. This is called an [indexed type query](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types)

```
interface MyProps {
    onEvent: (name: string, data: any) => void;
}

let eventHandler: MyProps['onEvent'] = (name, data) => {
    console.log(data);
}
```